# login to another application from my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have created a sample application say `comapny_portal.com`. Now I have another application `employee_portal.com`.

Now I am logged in to my `comapny_portal.com` using username and password. Now I am using same username and password for  `employee_portal.com`.

So I have added new link as **Company Employee Portal** from which I can login to my employee portal.

Is there any way from which I can login to that application. One way I am thinking about passing the username and password in the url. But I don't know how to pass username and password in the url.

So I have a following questions

- How can I pass username and password in the url.
- Is there any other way for implementing same functionality.

I am using rails Rails 2.3.14 and ruby 1.9.3
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> One way I am thinking about passing the username and password in the
>   url.

No.

You *can* do this using the `get` method (typically from a form):

```
<%= form_tag, "employee_portal.com", method: :get %>
   <%= text_field :username %>
   <%= password_field :password %>
   <%= submit_tag :your_submit %>
<% end %>
```

Because [`GET` requests send the data through the `url`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp), this will send the `username` and `password`over the HTTP request... but it's *insecure* and *highly inefficient*:

[image]

---

> Is there any way from which I can login to that application

As mentioned, [`single signon`](http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/) would be an option (`Grych`'s idea), oAuth could also be a solution you might want to consider:

[image]

The fundamental bottom line to all of this is that user data is the "holy of holies" - you cannot risk it in *any* way. You need to fortify & protect it with as much security as possible.

If someone has **trusted** you with their account information (especially password), you'll be best storing that data in a single secure location, allowing other data only to access it through pseudo-queries (such as through `oAuth` or an `API`)

I would personally use the single signon solution (not done it before, so will have to learn).

Answer (score 0):

Passing username and password in the URL is a very bad idea, your password will be exposed. What you are asking here is to how to create a **single signon** for multiple applications.

[Here](http://naveenagarwal287.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/ruby-on-rails-single-sign-on-across-multiple-applications/) is a concept how to do it. And [Here](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/) it is an interesting link I've found on this topic, it is done with custom oauth provider and devise.

Answer (score 0):

Just for those two applications under your control you could simply use a token with a shared secret that could be safely passed in a url:

```
def build_token(secret, loginname)
  ts = Time.now.to_i.to_s
  loginname + '-' + ts + '-' + Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(secret + loginname + ts)
end

def get_login_user(secret, token)
  valid_for = 60   # 1 minute valid
  elem = token.split '-'
  puts elem[1]
  if elem[1].to_i < Time.now.to_i - valid_for
    return nil      # token timeout
  elsif Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(secret + elem[0] + elem[1]) != elem[2]
    return nil      # wrong token
  else
    return elem[0]
  end
end
```

Now you can create a token for a logged in user on the one side:

> > build_token('mySecret123', 'hoeni')
> >         => "hoeni-1406629153-59d4f542373747793c6d60f34f3fb68db29816c0"

That can be passed in the url to the other side: http://employee_portal.com/token_login?token=hoeni-1406629153-59d4f542373747793c6d60f34f3fb68db29816c0

On the other side you can verify the token's integrity and get the trusted username to log in:

> > get_login_user('mySecret123', "hoeni-1406629153-59d4f542373747793c6d60f34f3fb68db29816c0")
> >         => "hoeni"

So anyone highjacking the URL could use that only for the given window of one minute to log in with the other server. (This could be even better if you include the remote IP address in the token)